# Sorting with unix tools and multiple columns

Tags: bash, unix, sorting, awk

I am looking for the easiest way to solve this problem. I have a huge data set that i cannot load into excel of this type of format

```
This is a sentence|10
This is another sentence|5
This is the last sentence|20
```

What I want to do is sort this from least to greatest based on the number.

```
cat MyDataSet.txt | tr "|" "\t" | ???
```

Not sure what the best way is to do this, I was thinking about using awk to switch the columns and the do a sort, but I was having trouble doing it.

Help me out please

Comment: Yes, you can import this type of data into Excel, if you import as text, then specify "|" as the delimiter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
sort -t\| -k +2n dataset.txt
```

Should do it.  field separator and alternate key selection

Comment: What is the purpose of the `+` in `+2`?

Comment: To move the sort from focusing on the first delimited group to the second delimited group.

Comment: @brandizzi: Habit. Older versions of sort used + and - to signal what columns to sort on and what to not sort on. GNU sort uses a different technique that doesn't require it (but also doesn't barf on +)

Comment: Means sort numerically on the second column. Although obsolete this notation works. The use of the `-k 2,2n` notation is recommended, at least on GNU sort.

Comment: What is the purpose for the 'n' in +2n or in 2,2n? Does it mean next? There is nothing about an 'n' in man sort. Seems like sort -t \| -k 2,2 dataset.txt works as well.

Comment: @Alexander: The "n" mean numeric.  In other words, assume that the second argument is a number so that 5 sorts before 10.  When used in the context I used it, it applies the n argument only to argument 2.  This is irrelevant since there is only one sort key, but for more complex commands it can be important.

Answer (score 13):

You usually don't need cat to send the file to a filter. That said, you can use the *sort* filter.

```
sort -t "|" -k 2 -n MyDataSet.txt
```

This sorts the MyDataSet.txt file using the | character as field separator and sorting numerically according to the second field (the number).

Answer (score 7):

have you tried sort -n

```
$ sort -n inputFile
This is another sentence|5
This is a sentence|10
This is the last sentence|20
```

you could switch the columns with awk too

```
$ awk -F"|" '{print $2"|"$1}' inputFile
10|This is a sentence
5|This is another sentence
20|This is the last sentence
```

combining awk and sort:

```
$ awk -F"|" '{print $2"|"$1}' inputFile | sort -n
5|This is another sentence
10|This is a sentence
20|This is the last sentence
```

**per comments**

if you have numbers in the sentence

```
$ sort -n -t"|" -k2 inputFile
This is another sentence|5
This is a sentence|10
This is the last sentence|20
this is a sentence with a number in it 2|22
```

and of course you could redirect it to a new file:

```
$ awk -F"|" '{print $2"|"$1}' inputFile | sort -n > outFile
```

Comment: true, I was going off the example he had copied.

Answer (score 3):

Try this sort command:

```
sort -n -t '|' -k2 file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort by number, change the separator and grab the second group using sort.

```
sort -n -t'|' -k2 dataset.txt
```