# Sorting by column Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am working on a script and I am stuck at one stage. I would like to sort/uniq depending on the column, please help on the below

```
229984:usto:150:usto-pdbx-sql13.amgen.com:usto-inf-srvr-W2008phys-prd-w
229986:usto:156:usto-pdbx-sql13.amgen.com:usto-inf-srvr-W2008phys-prd-w
230187:usto:50:usto-tsvc-smp03.amgen.com:usto-inf-srvr-W2008phys-tst-r
230713:usto:58:USTO271389-s.amgen.com:usto-inf-silv-EDM_windows-prd-u
229814:usto:58:usto-sec-iss-am.amgen.com:usto-inf-silv-security_app-prd-t
229618:usto:59:usto-pdpx-me020.amgen.com:usto-dev-brnz-matlabDev_app_NFS-prd-r
229255:usto:84:usto-dsvc-emfb1:usto-idm-silv-arcot_windows-dev-f
```

In in the above I would like to remove the whole line depending onthe 3 and 4th column. If any row in 3 and 4 entry repeats I would like to remove the same.

Please suggest on this thanks.

Comment: Start with sort --field-separator=: -k3 -k4 -u and see how that works for you. If the option interplay in sort gets too complex, I'd switch to awk.

Comment: so can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate in part of sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295710/sorting-with-unix-tools-and-multiple-columnss.

`sort -t: -k +3n` and `sort -t: -k +4n` will sort as you want. In addition, add `-u` option to skip duplicates.

Comment: Your question as it is currently written is unclear. Please define your desired output text based upon your input above. Also, show what code you have tried.

Comment: in your example data, no line has same col3 **and** col4, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of ugly bash hacking, so why not just have some beautiful python instead?

```
seen_col_3 = []
seen_col_4 = []

for line in s.split():
  cols = line.split(":")
  if cols[3] in seen_col_3 and cols[4] in seen_col_4:
    continue
  seen_col_3.append(cols[3])
  seen_col_4.append(cols[4])
  print line
```

now you only need to read the file into `s`

Comment: Use of set insteed of list is more appropriate. Changing s.split() with open(filename), removes loading file in a string.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can help.

`C3` stores all different values in column 3, and `C4` different values in column 4.

```
{
if( !($3 in C3) && !($4 in C4) ) { print; }
C3[$3] = 1; C4[$4] = 1;
}
```

Call it by:

```
awk -F':' -f<file_with_upper_code> <file>
```

Or if you have stdout:

```
program | awk -F':' -f<file_with_upper_code>
```

Answer (score 0):

first change `:` between 3rd and 4th columns to something like `###`, then `sort` on `-k3` and at last change `###` to `:`

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*\):/\1###/' file | sort -t':' -k3 -u | sed 's/###/:/'
```

UPDATE:
See [sed Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lG2dM0)